# How to join on a function/subquery in Access 2010?

Tags: sql, function, ms-access, join, subquery

I know exactly how to do this in SQL, but unfortunately due to IT decisions I have to do this in Access 2010.

How do I accomplish the following query in Access 2010?

```
Select a.Column1
, a.Column2
from table1 as a
where Left(a.Column2,3) in (Select distinct(b.Column3) from table2 as b)
```

**Note:** I do not want to select all of the records from table1 and in a subsequent query filter out the records that do not meet the constraints specified in the where clause.  This solution will select 5.6M records, instead of only the 100K necessary records.

Comment: Have you tried this query?  It looks like it would work, although the `distinct` is unnecessary.

Comment: As @GordonLinoff said pretty sure the query you posted should work in Access.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Previously, it was giving me an error message with something to the effect of not being able to have aggregate functions (part of my debugging process was taking out all other constraints) in a where clause/expression. Today all it is doing is taking over 30 minutes and counting and still has MS Access in a 'Not Responding' state. Just to gauge, I ran this same query in less than 45 seconds in SQL on the same data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If performance is the issue, try rephrasing as a `join`:

```
Select a.Column1, a.Column2
from table1 as a join
     (Select distinct b.Column3 from table2 as b)
     on Left(a.Column2, 3) = b.Column3;
```

However, if you have the opportunity to use a more functional database such as SQL Server I encourage you to embrace the opportunity.

Answer (score -1):

In Access, you save a query like a file.  So, I usually would save

```
SELECT DISTINCT(b.Column3) FROM table 2 as b)
```

as 001_query and then the next query would be

```
SELECT a.Column1, a.Column2 FROM table1 as a, 001_query b WHERE findfunction!results = TRUE
```

If you are using the visual query editor, you have to use the "Show Table" button in the Design tab, then in the resulting window you should be able to add table a, and then click on the query tab to add 001_query.

Comment: Please see the section called "Note" in my original post.